# simple pole of two variable meromorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathbb{H}$ be a complex upper half plane.

Let $H(z,\tau):\mathbb{H}\times\mathbb{H}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$

Then author says that $H(z,\tau)$ is meromorphic on $\mathbb{H}\times\mathbb{H}$ with simple poles when $z=\tau$.

I understand what it means for being meromorphic on $\mathbb{H}\times\mathbb{H}$

However I do not understand what simple pole means.(More generally, order of pole can be defined?)

In one variable case, there are well known definition of order of pole via laurent expansion.

Any reference or short explanation will be thankful.

Comment: I would say that simple pole here means that locally near the diagonal the function looks like $\frac{c(z, \tau)}{z-\tau}$ with $c(z, \tau)$ holomorphic $c(z,z)$ not identically zero (or maybe not zero at all);

Comment: @Conrad Thank you for explanation! I have a one more question. Let $f$ be holomorphic function on upper half plane. Then $\frac{1}{f(z)-f(\tau)}$ is meromorphic function on $\mathbb{H}\times\mathbb{H}$ and has a pole at $z=\tau$. Can we say that this pole is simple??

Comment: not necessarily - if $f$ is conformal (not necessarily injective, just that $f'(z) \ne 0$ for all $z$ then yes

Comment: @Conrad Thank you very much!

Comment: happy to be of help